# how to get something value from a sql group by query, where data is null

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

initially i have a empty table in a database named *comments*. 
no row input given here.
it has 4 columns, 3 foreign key of those. 
i wrote a query on it like that -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `comments` 
GROUP BY posts_id
```

it returns nothing because the table is completely empty. 
but i must need at least **0** by this query for confirming table is empty or if it has value then return me the value.
or any other option to check that the table is null , it has no row.

(currently i am testing the query in mysql. later, i will convert it in Laravel query builders and use it in a laravel app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` with a query that returns `0` in case the table is empty:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `comments` 
GROUP BY posts_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `comments`)
```

If you are using MySql 8.0+ you can omit `FROM dual`.